# Can't access Mail or Mail setttings on iphone 4 + iOS 6.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios

Since the upgrade to iOS 6, I've been unable to access my mail on wi-fi, cellular or disconnected.

The symptoms are:

- The mail button icon shows '1'
- When clicking on te mail app icon, it attempts to open up the app, then it times out and goes back to the home screen
- When clicking on settings -> Mail, Contacts, and Calendars, the phone gets stuck and times out then goes back to the home screen.

Comment: A few queries: what mail accounts did you have in there, standard IMAP style (Gmail, Yahoo!, etc.), or custom POP3 style accounts? I'm sure you have, but, you have rebooted the phone, right? What about backing up to iCloud (and iTunes, if you want) and restoring the device? Can you go to Settings > iCloud > Account?

Comment: Not an answer- I have the same problem 4S IOS 6.1.3. Gmail and charter email account.
Everything works on my MacBook Pro. Mail icon shows 20. Tap it and I get a white screen for 1-2 secs then closes to the main screen. Same thing happens when I choose mail under settings. No restrictions. Have tried to restart and reset after shutting down mail. Have not done factory reset, want to see if there is a fix.

Answer (score 2):

First, force-quit Mail.app. To do this: Go to your home screen. Double-click the home screen. Locate Mail.app in the bottom bar that appears. Press and hold Mail.app until the icons wiggle. Delete Mail.app from the bottom bar by clicking red X.

Try again to launch Mail. If this doesn't work, reset the iPhone by pressing and holding power and home buttons for 10 seconds. Restart device once it shuts off.

Comment: Thanks! but It didn't work. iOS didn't let me delete it. It freezes again

Answer (score 1):

- you could try this, though it's unlikely since you can see the mail icon

  1. Try going to the Settings.app.
  2. Once inside: General>>
  3. scroll down and select "Restrictions" (this is at the bottom
  4. Make sure Mail is both 'allowed' ('On') and that Restrictions are disabled, unless you want them enabled. (Restrictions are *disabled* if all your apps are light in color/unsaturated (grayed out), **and** the button at the top of the screen reads "Enable Restrictions").
- second, you could do a factory reset/restore, then restore from your latest or last known good backup. Hopefully your mail messages exist in such a way that you can reset/restore without losing anything. (Depends on mail settings. If you are using POP and you have unsent drafts you will likely lose them. If you are using IMAP you *should* be fine, but I can't guarantee this.
- I would definitely do the steps bispymusic suggested.
- to clarify,

  1. Using the "Slide to power off" then holding both buttons to turn the device back on is called a 'Restart', and is considered more topical.
  2. Holding both buttons while the device is *on* until the logo shows up again is called a 'Reset' and is used for more severe ('deeper') issues that don't go away after a 'Restart'.

Comment: Restrictions are off. I think my best option forward is to perhaps factory reinstall

Comment: Factory restore is my suggestion now given the feedback you've provided both of us.

Comment: Yes, do report if it works out, or not.